# Postgres trigger duplicating rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

This trigger function worked properly up until two weeks ago.  Now it is returning multiple/duplicate rows. It's almost as though the inner join is returning multiple '1' values for the row_number function.  When the function is run independently of the trigger it returns the correct amount of rows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_capsw AFTER INSERT ON improper_pay.capsw 
EXECUTE FUNCTION improper_pay.refresh_tickets_capsw()
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION improper_pay.refresh_tickets_capsw()


  RETURNS trigger


  LANGUAGE plpgsql


 AS $function$
         declare
                 v_affected_row_count INTEGER;
                 v_max_c_day VARCHAR(25);
         begin
                 v_max_c_day := (select max(c_today) as max_c_today from improper_pay.capsw);
                 -- Delete records with the same trigger date but earlier time.
                 delete from improper_pay.capsw where c_today <> v_max_c_day and c_today >= substring(v_max_c_day, 1, 8);
                 v_affected_row_count :=  ( select count(*) from (
                         select distinct
                                 trans.uot_dfas_site as agency,
                                 trans.uot_source as system1,
                                 trans.uot_source as system2,
                                 trans.uotsys_databasename as "docId",
                                 trans.uot_flag_integrity_check as "resolutionOther",
                                 ARRAY[trans.uotsys_groupid] as "refId",
                                 now() as "createdAt",
                                 now() as "updatedAt",
                                 6 as type,
                                 1 as priority,
                                 (select id from public."Statuses" where upper(name) = 'NEW TICKET') as status,
                                                 'SYSTEM_GENERATED' as "reporterUserId",
                                                 'SYSTEM_GENERATED' as "reporterUserName",
                                                 'UNASSIGNED' as "assigneeUserId",
                                                 'UNASSIGNED' as "assigneeUserName",
                                                 now() as "dueDate"
                                 from improper_pay.capsw trans
                                         left join public."Tickets" t
                                                 on trans.uotsys_groupid = t."refId"[1]
                                                         and t.type = 6
                                                         and t.system2 = 'CAPSW'
                                 where t.type is NULL
                                         and trans.c_today = v_max_c_day
                                         and trans.uot_triggering = 'TRIGGERING'
                                         and trans.uot_dfas_site is NOT NULL
                                         and trans.uot_source is NOT NULL
                                         and trans.uotsys_databasename is NOT NULL)x);
                 if v_affected_row_count <= 2000 then

                         insert into public."Tickets" (agency, system1, system2, "docId", "resolutionOther", "refId", "createdAt", "updatedAt", type, priority, status, "reporterUserId", "reporterUserName", "assigneeUserId", "assigneeUser
Name", "dueDate", extra_fields)+



                         select distinct
                                 trans.uot_dfas_site as agency,
                                 trans.uot_source as system1,
                                 trans.uot_source as system2,
                                 trans.uotsys_databasename as "docId",
                                 trans.uot_flag_integrity_check as "resolutionOther",
                                 ARRAY[trans.uotsys_groupid] as "refId",
                                 now() as "createdAt",
                                 now() as "updatedAt",
                                 6 as type,
                                 1 as priority,
                                 (select id from public."Statuses" where upper(name) = 'NEW TICKET') as status,
                                                 'SYSTEM_GENERATED' as "reporterUserId",
                                                 'SYSTEM_GENERATED' as "reporterUserName",
                                                 'UNASSIGNED' as "assigneeUserId",
                                                 'UNASSIGNED' as "assigneeUserName",
                                                 now() as "dueDate",
                                 concat(
                                         '{',
                                         '"uot_fullcontract":"', data.uot_fullcontract, '",',
                                         '"uot_shipmentnum":"', data.uot_shipmentnum, '",',
                                         '"uot_invoicenum":"', data.uot_invoicenum, '",',
                                         '"uot_signedamount":', data.uot_signedamount, ',',
                                         '"uot_invoiceid":"', data.uot_invoiceid, '",',
                                         '"uot_cagecode":"', data.uot_cagecode, '",',
                                         '"uot_ordernum":"', data.uot_ordernum, '",',
                                         '"uot_potentialimpact":', data.uot_potentialimpact, '',
                                         '}'
                                 )::jsonb
                                 from improper_pay.capsw trans
                                         left join public."Tickets" t
                                                 on trans.uotsys_groupid = t."refId"[1]
                                                         and t.type = 6
                                                         and t.system2 = 'CAPSW'
                                         join (
                                                 select
                                                         uotsys_groupid,
                                                         trim(uot_fullcontract) as uot_fullcontract,
                                                         '' as uot_shipmentnum,
                                                         trim(replace(uot_invoicenum, cast(chr(x'09'::int) as character varying),'')) as uot_invoicenum,
                                                         coalesce(uot_signedamount,0) as uot_signedamount,
                                                         '' as uot_invoiceid,
                                                         trim(replace(uot_cagecode, cast(chr(x'09'::int) as character varying),'')) as uot_cagecode,
                                                         '' as uot_ordernum,
                                                         coalesce(uot_potentialimpact,0) as uot_potentialimpact,
                                                         row_number() over (partition by uotsys_groupid) as rn
                                                 from improper_pay.capsw
                                         ) data
                                                 on trans.uotsys_groupid = data.uotsys_groupid
                                                         and data.rn = 1
                                 where t.type is NULL
                                         and trans.c_today = v_max_c_day
                                         and trans.uot_triggering = 'TRIGGERING'
                                         and trans.uot_dfas_site is NOT NULL
                                         and trans.uot_source is NOT NULL
                                         and trans.uotsys_databasename is NOT NULL
 ;
                 end if;

                 return new;

         end;

         $function$
```

Comment: What is the `CREATE TRIGGER` definition? What is the function supposed to be doing? Add information as update to question.

Comment: ```CREATE TRIGGER trig_capsw AFTER INSERT ON improper_pay.capswEXECUTE FUNCTION improper_pay.refresh_tickets_capsw()
```

Comment: Per request add the information as update to your question. Also explain what the function is supposed  to be doing? Also, are you really storing dates as strings?

Comment: Added to original question
The trigger is supposed to insert records into the public."Tickets" table after transaction results are pushed to improper_pay.capsw.  Yes, the date values are being stored as string.